# Is it anti-pattern to use BuildContext in Riverpod Notifier?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

```
@riverpod
class Foo extends _$Foo {
  @override
  void build() {
    return;
  }

  // Use BuildContext in Notifier
  Future<void> complexFunction(BuildContext context) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    if (context.mounted){
      final result = await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return const Dialog();
        },
      );

      // .... many etc function ...
    }
  }
}
```

Sorry if this is a basic question.

I searching many around but haven't gotten a clear answer to the above question.

Is there a problem with using BuildContext in a Notifier like above?

Comment: Riverpod is intended for models, not views, and should never need "context".  The consumer of this riverpod model should act with its own context in tow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm checked an official update to Riverpod lint for this.

https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod_lint/changelog#220---2023-10-02

> Added avoid_build_context_in_providers

The bottom line should not be used. It is an Anti-Pattern.